# The given key was not present in the dictionary?

Tags: json, vb.net

I having trouble deserializing this JSON.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "ticker": {
        "high": 91.489,
        "low": 88.3,
        "avg": 89.8945,
        "vol": 233637.9876,
        "vol_cur": 2588.09448,
        "last": 90.48,
        "buy": 90.55,
        "sell": 90.48,
        "updated": 1372613806,
        "server_time": 1372613807
    }
}
```

And my function is this:

```
Private Function Btce(ByVal Address As String) As String
    Dim rt As String = ""
    Dim out As String
    Dim wRequest As WebRequest
    Dim wResponse As WebResponse
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    Dim Time As Date

    Time = Now()
    wRequest = WebRequest.Create(Address)
    wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse

    SR = New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream)
    rt = SR.ReadToEnd
    SR.Close()

    Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim testObj = js.Deserialize(rt, New Object().GetType())
    Dim high = testObj("High")
    Dim low = testObj("Low")
    Dim avg = testObj("Average")
    Dim vol = testObj("Volume")
    Dim last = testObj("Last")
    Dim buy = testObj("Buy")
    Dim sell = testObj("Sell")

    out = "Data from btc-e.com" + Environment.NewLine
    out += (Time) + Environment.NewLine
    out += "High: " + Environment.NewLine
    out += "Low: " + Environment.NewLine
    out += "Average: " + Environment.NewLine
    out += "Volume: " + Environment.NewLine
    out += "Last: " + Environment.NewLine
    out += "Buy: " + Environment.NewLine
    out += "Sell: "

    Return out
End Function
```

Then I get this in the console:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>   Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Might be a issue with case sensitivity.

Comment: I recommend to tag your question with the language you are using. The question will most likely get more attention then.

Comment: Does `testObj("ticker")` work?

Comment: I tried Dim tickerusdbtc = testObj("ticker") and added + tickerusdbtc("high") to each out line but i get same error.

Comment: @SkiloSkilo I've updated my answer and tested it. I had made a mistake earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is that you are looking for "Average" in testObj, but in the JSON it is "avg". And you are also looking for "Volume", not "vol".

In addition, the data returned by the deserialization is not a straight collection, it is a System.Collections.Dictionary(Of String, Object) where there is one entry for each of the representing the ticker objects in the json.

Each ticker object contains a String Key and a Value where Value is a System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair, which is case-sensitive. Value contains the collection of data (i.e. "high", 9.4189).

Based on this, your code should look like:

```
    Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim cObjects = js.Deserialize(rt, New Object().GetType())

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim out As New System.Text.StringBuilder(1000)

    ' Use a stringbuilder to capture the output; much more efficient than constant string concat
    out.Append("Data from btc-e.com").AppendLine()

    For Each testObj In cObjects
        Dim high = testObj.Value("high")
        Dim low = testObj.Value("low")
        Dim avg = testObj.Value("avg")
        Dim vol = testObj.Value("vol")
        Dim last = testObj.Value("last")
        Dim buy = testObj.Value("buy")
        Dim sell = testObj.Value("sell")

        ' Since you will be processing multiple records, show something 
        ' in the output about where you are 
        counter += 1

        out.Append("Element ").Append(counter).AppendLine()
        out.Append(DateTime.Now).AppendLine()
        out.Append("High: ").Append(high).AppendLine()
        out.Append("Low: ").Append(low).AppendLine()
        out.Append("Average: ").Append(avg).AppendLine()
        out.Append("Volume: ").Append(vol).AppendLine()
        out.Append("Last: ").Append(last).AppendLine()
        out.Append("Buy: ").Append(buy).AppendLine()
        out.Append("Sell: ").Append(sell).AppendLine()
    Next

    Return out.ToString()
```

Comment: But i declared avg as Average with: Dim avg = testObj("Average")

Comment: @SkiloSkilo: All you have done is declare a local value as avg, you have not changed how you access the value in the collection. Please see the revised answer for more information.

Comment: Like this? out += "High: " + cObjects("high") + Environment.NewLine
        out += "Low: " + cObjects("low") + Environment.NewLine
        out += "Average: " + cObjects("avg") + Environment.NewLine
        out += "Volume: " + cObjects("vol") + Environment.NewLine
        out += "Last: " + cObjects("last") + Environment.NewLine
        out += "Buy: " + cObjects("buy") + Environment.NewLine
        out += "Sell: " + cObjects("sell")

Comment: No, that won't work. Please see the revised answer. Makes use of stringbuilder to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

1. When deserializing to an object graph, you can just use `DeserializeObject`
2. The keys you are looking for are not present under the object you've just deserialized, but are in fact keys of the object under `"ticker"`.
3. The default equality comparer used for dictionaries is probably case sensitive. You might want to construct a new dictionary while explicitly specifying `StringComparer.***IgnoreCase`, where *** is any of `Ordinal`, `InvariantCulture` or `CurrentCulture`.

For example:

```
Dim testObj = js.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Single)))(rt)("ticker")

testObj = New Dictionary(Of String, Single)(testObj, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Dim high = testObj("High")
```